# ATI Radeon 4550 HD

Tags: 16.04

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS yesterday and since I'm totally new to this I got stuck at installing/updating graphic driver.
My graphic card is named on the title of topic.
I seek help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD proprietary drivers are not supported in 16.04, nor will AMD ever update their drivers for 16.04. Ex: `fglrx`.

To use them you should downgrade to 14.04. If you are fine with using the open-source drivers there is no need to install anything.

Comment: that sucks :( is there any slight difference between 14.04 and 16.04 ?

Comment: @therzok 16.04 has `systemd`, a newer kernel, and some other features. Both are LTS releases, which means if you downgrade to 14.04 you will still get support until late 2019. You will get better performance in games if you downgrade and use the `fglrx` driver. If my answer helped please mark it as correct.